# Google Sites api non-latin language encoding issue

Tags: encoding, utf-8, google-api, google-sites

I'm programming with Google sites api's.
My requests body consist parameters such as site `title` and `category` in non Latin language (Hebrew and Arab).
After the requests are done I see the site title and category name in `???` characters,
which is obviously an encoding problem.
Tried to change and request `ContentType` header to `application/atom+xml;charset=UTF-8` from `application/atom+xml`
but it's not helping.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using ASCII to html encoding did the trick for me.
Online Converter http://succulent-plant.com/toys/asciitohtml.html

The C# function:

```
   public string ConvertToHtmlEncoding(string inpString)
    {

        string outString="";
        for (var i = 0; i < inpString.Length; i++)

        {

            outString += "&#"+((int)inpString[i]).ToString()+";";

        }

        return outString;
    }
```